# Locking the local SVN files

Tags: svn, locking

I want to:

1. update the file to a certain revision
2. lock the working copy so no one else can update or modify it
3. run a compile script (seperate to svn and quite slow)
4. unlock file so other users can modify again

this is what I wrote (in windows command line syntax):

```
svn update file.cpp --force -r 320
svn lock file.cpp 
Call CompileScript.exe
svn unlock file.cpp
```

However unfortunately another user ran an update on file.cpp whilst I was compiling, and it reverted to the latest version in the repository again i.e. it wasn't stopped by the lock.

Is there any way of locking the working copy so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

The svn lock command is to stop commits/merging on the repository end of things, it will not stop someone modifying or changing your local file.  You could make it read only in DOS?  I think it's attrib +r, then remove it with attrib -r afterwards.

Comment: I'm afraid making them read only in dos does not solve the problem. I've had a thought that if I modify the scripts people use to run CompileScript.exe, so that it checks the working revision, prior to running the 'update' command. This should prevent people modifying file.cpp, whilst CompileScript.exe is running.

Comment: Damn. :/  Not sure what else to suggest apart from some svn hook that will block updates/checkouts/reverts etc. if any files are locked.  But how to go about writing such a hook, if indeed one is possible I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You want to LOCK the LOCAL copy of the file? That's an OS thing, and has nothing to do with Subversion. What are you trying to do where everyone and their cousin has read/write privileges to files you need to control?

Version control systems already have the built in means of doing what you want, but you need to use a working directory directly under your control. Users should never share working directories just for this reason. If you need a cooperative space, create a branch, but never share working directories.

I guess you could use the [cacls](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html) command to remove read/write privileges, but if you are working under the same user id as others, those other people can simply grant themselves the permission right back.